# Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor (): method body is empty

Tags: asp.net, mono, invalidprogramexception

I am Japanese developer,so English is a strange sorry. I am deploying an asp.net web project to a Mono linux box. I had the skeleton working pretty nice, but when I started Building in , I got the error you see above.

I've set the dll to copy local and added it to the bin_System.Drawing.dll and `bin_System.Drowing.Design.dll` folder, with no success.

It seems like I'm missing something simple. Any guesses what it is?

Server Error in '/' Application

Invalid IL code in `System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor ():` method body is empty.

Description: `HTTP 500. Error processing request.`

Stack Trace:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor (): method body is empty.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/ColorConverter.cs or http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ColorConverter.cs.html#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ColorConverter.cs,f7a77b0f8c6058e8 constructors in this 2 implemeantion are empty.

Comment: Please tell me what to do can I use that source .